# JQuery dynamically added image preview is not showing with crossorigin attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `img` tag which have `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute. This attribute is required here. Now I have list of images. On clicking on any one of those image, `src` is getting updated with clicked image `src` on that `img` tag which have `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute. Now the problem I am facing is, if clicked image is in same server it works fine but if it is an external link then this image preview is not working.

This is what I have done to put the clicked image `src` into `img` tag `src` attribute,

```
$(".js-image img").on('click', function(){
  $("#image-id").attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
});
```

This is my `img` tag where image `src` need to be placed

```
<img src="/img/348106734.jpg" alt="" id="image-id" width="100%;" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: check your console, you will see why the request fails, why do you use crossorigin attribute?

Comment: Request is not failing. Everything is getting updated properly. Just preview is not showing

Comment: there must be a network tab where you see the actual img request. If this does not fail your image would be displayed.

Comment: remove the attribut crossorigin

Comment: As I mentioned above, this crossorigin is required